# Calling method from AWK command

Tags: ksh

I have varibales which represent order numer

I want to parse it and call to method handleOrder

I tried it but not working

```
 #!/bin/ksh
ORDER_LIST=100,200,300
`echo $line |awk -F"," '{for(i=0;i<=NF;i++) HandleOrder printf $i}'`

HandleOrder 
(
 echo "My Order is $1"
}
```

Expected Result:

```
My Order is 100
My Order is 200
My Order is 300
```

Actual Result

```
Syntax Error
```

Comment: @SimonC is correct. I would ask 'why do you think you need backquotes surrounding the whole command?' 1. Backquotes are deprecated, use `$( cmd )` unless you're sure your code will be used with Sun, etc original Bourne shell. 2. `$( ... )` and backquotes are both a shell featured called command-substitution. Your example doesn't need it. Something like `var=$(...cmd..)` would be an appropriate use of command substition. There are other uses. 3. If you're going to do shell programming regularly, get out of the habit of using CSV data ;-)! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the `HandleOrder` function inside the awk script so that it can be called in the awk script.  Also, you want to start your loop at 1 so that you do not print `$0`, the variable that contains the whole line.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ORDER_LIST=100,200,300
echo $ORDER_LIST | awk -F"," '
  function HandleOrder(order) { print "My Order is ", order } 
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { HandleOrder($i) }}
'
```

If you wish to have `HandleOrder` as a shell script instead of an awk function, then use something like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ORDER_LIST=100,200,300
echo $ORDER_LIST | awk -F"," '
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { system("HandleOrder.ksh " $i) }}
'
```

and create a shell script named `HandleOrder.ksh` containing:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "My Order is $1"
```

Make sure that `HandleOrder.ksh` is set executable and is in the `$PATH`.

Comment: Hi,

it;s working fine ,but is there a way to decalre the HandleOrder out of the AWK ,because my HandleOrder method is more than 500 lines.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a second example showing how to make HandleOrder.ksh a separate shell script.